# Delphi FireDAC Firebird programatically get execution plan

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

Delphi (Tokyo and Rio), FireDAC and Firebird 2.5: How do I programatically (not using an external tool) get the execution plan info on a query?  I.e., I have a query component and have given it the SQL SELECT statement and params - how do I (a) get the plan before opening the query, and/or (b) get the plan after the query has been opened?  It would seem like info that would be easy to find, but I've searched the web multiple times with no joy, and even Cary Jensen's FireDAC book doesn't contain an index or TOC reference to plans.

Comment: did you try grepping FireDAC sources ? find a constant equal to Firebird's `#define isc_info_sql_get_plan  22` in FireDAC sources, then find which functions might use it, then find which functions might call those functions, etc

Comment: @Arioch, sorry, that one is not (yet) implemented. Surely one can extend FireDAC and optimally post the solution to EMBT to implement it, but nobody did that yet. Besides, I don't quite believe FB would make 2 execution plans (one for command preparation and one for its execution).

Comment: @TLama plan would be the same of course. Plan is generated during preparation phase, which can be explicit (then you can query the plan "before opening") or implicit (then - after query was opened). The plan is one and the same of course

Comment: A search for that const turned up a couple references, and at least one of the other physical-layer drivers includes support for plans, but not the Firebird/IB driver.  I guess I was expecting a SQL statement or the like to retrieve it, or support in FireDAC in some across-the-board, driver-neutral manner. FlameRobin includes the plan as part of the stats on an executed query, so it's available *somehow* (tho' what FlameRobin shows for the plan is pretty thin compared to what you get from SQL Server or Oracle.)

Comment: You would read plan from `TIBStatement(FDQuery1.Command.CommandIntf.CliObj).sql_get_plan;`, but this property is not implemented. Try to implement it, maybe you'll be lucky (how to you can find in the source). I'm out of Delphi right now.

Comment: @SteveS - Firebird 3 introduced more verbose, "explained" plan (and another constant to request it). I don't know if FlameRobin can show it. You may try IBExpert trial or personal version to see.

Comment: Slightly related https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3257/33635 - discussing Firebird API, so you can implement it in your code

Comment: Thanks to you both.  For now, I'll just test queries in FlameRobin if I need to see the plan.  Too many higher-priority tasks on my plate to spend time implementing this now.

Comment: @Arioch, as far as I remember, I was trying the `isc_info_sql_get_plan` member and it did not return anything in some FB around version 2.5. Maybe they fixed that since then. Except that one, FB 3 added `isc_info_sql_explain_plan` member (but that one is also not used anywhere in FireDAC).

Comment: @TLama i would look into UIB or IBX sources for working examples of implementing it in Delphi. But i did not do it myself :D